# Como enviar corretamente o valor de uma variável nula em um INSERT?

Tags: c#, sql

Supondo que eu tenha o seguinte código:

```
public async void InsertBanco(string parametro1, string parametro2)
{
    var b = new BancoN();
    SetBanco(b);
    await b.EnviaMySQLInsert($"INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) " +
    $"VALUES('{parametro1}','{parametro2}') ;");
 }
```

Em algumas situações o `parametro2` pode ser nulo, como faço para enviar `NULL` no `insert`?

Se eu chamar `InsertBanco("Teste", null)`, por exemplo, o sql ficaria assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) VALUES('Teste','');
```

E se eu enviar a string com o valor "NULL" (`InsertBanco("Teste", "NULL")`), essa string vai ser inserida no banco, ao invés de setar o valor como nulo.

Mas o correto seria:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) VALUES('Teste', NULL);
```

Como posso corrigir esse problema?

---

**EDIT**

Esclarecendo o problema: em alguns casos o `parametro2` vai ser nulo e em alguns casos vai ser uma `string`("Texto", por exemplo).

Quando é uma `string`, o código que eu tenho funciona normalmente.
Mas quando eu precisar setar nulo no banco, do jeito que foi escrito o código nunca vai funcionar...

Como escrever o método `InsertBanco` de forma que ele consiga enviar o sql correto quando o `parametro2` é nulo e quando for uma `string` normal??

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92944/discussion-on-question-by-artur-brasil-enviar-valor-nulo-no-insert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a query:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) VALUES('parametro1', NULLIF ('parametro2', ''));
```

Comment: +1 e + um muito obrigado. Eu não sabia da existência desse [NULLIF](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Também não conhecia o `NULLIF`, acho que esse é o modo que melhor resolve meu problema.

Comment: Coloque na configuração da tabela o campo com Default/Expression como NULL, ai toda vez que o campo for vazio, ele deixa como NULL.

Comment: No caso seria sem as aspas, certo? `NULLIF (parametro2, '')`

Comment: Depende do que vai ser usado na query, se será string ou não, caso seja, é necessário passar com aspas.

Answer (score 4):

Teste se `parametro2` é nulo e construa o Insert adequado.
Qualquer coisa assim:

```
public async void InsertBanco(string parametro1, string parametro2)
{
    var b = new BancoN();
    SetBanco(b);
    if(parametro2 == null)
    {
        await b.EnviaMySQLInsert($"INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1) " +
                                 $"VALUES('{parametro1}') ;");
        return;
    }
    await b.EnviaMySQLInsert($"INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) " +
                             $"VALUES('{parametro1}','{parametro2}') ;");
 }
```

Comment: Funciona nesse caso, mas se eu tivesse mais o "parametro3" e "parametro4", e esses parametros também pudesse receber null, teria que ter um if para cada uma das possibilidades. `if(parametro3 == null)` ; `if(parametro2 == null && parametro3 == null)` ; `if(parametro2 == null && parametro4 == null)` ...

Comment: Eu sempre respondo ao que é perguntado :).

Comment: É uma resposta válida :)

Comment: Veja a resposta do @Sumback, parece-me a mais adequada.

Answer (score 4):

Use uma expressão condicional para verificar se `parametro2` é vazio ou nulo

```
await b.EnviaMySQLInsert( $"INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) VALUES('{parametro1}', { ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(parametro2)) ? "NULL" : ("'" + parametro2 + "'") )}); ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se o `parametro2` está vazio, se tiver passe `NULL`, senão passe o valor do `parametro2`.

```
await b.EnviaMySQLInsert($"INSERT INTO tabela(parametro1, parametro2) " + 
                         $"VALUES('{parametro1}'," + parametro2 == "" ? "NULL);" : $"'{parametro2}');");
```